# Output vertex pair(s) whose distance is the graph's diameter

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Assuming you have a connected graph (in my case also undirected and equal/no edge weights), how could you see all the vertex pairs whose shortest length path is equal to the graph's diameter?

An implementation of Floyd–Warshall algorithm would work, and it sounds like there are slightly faster implementations to the problem. As of now I'm just looping over every pair and running FindShortestPath.

Maybe you can somehow get access to the pair(s) used to output the longest minimum path with the built-in Diameter function?

Comment: how about `diameterPairs[g_?ConnectedGraphQ] := 
 Module[{dm = GraphDistanceMatrix[g]}, Position[dm, Max[dm]]]` or `diameterPairs2[g_?ConnectedGraphQ] := Position[GraphDistanceMatrix[g], GraphDiameter[g]]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IGFindDiameter` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/). It will return the path corresponding to the diameter. You can take the first/last elements as the endpoints.